# Create new docker container with composer 2.0 installed

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laradock

I am very new to docker and laradock, but I am trying to figure out how to create a new container that comes with composer 2.0 (or latest) installed automatically?  How do I tell Laradock that I want the latest composer upon build/creation of the container?

I have followed several tutorials and several posts about this type of situation...however, nothing has panned out.   If I build the container, and start the workspace bash, it comes up with composer 1.10 every time.   I can update it from within the container, but I would prefer to have it installed by default, when the container is created.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Two that spring to mind are:

1. You can use the [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) command in your docker file to run pretty much any commands
   you like. So you could in theory install composer this way.
2. You can manually install composer and then [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) a new image. The new image will contain the composer install. You then push that to your repo of choice and use it as the base image in your dockerfile. This is quite common practice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I think I will follow option 2.
Just so I am clear, I would install composer from within the container:
composer self-update --2

Then, "down" the container and rebuild the workspace container:
docker-compose build --no-cache workspace

And then commit these changes to my repo with the workspace code in it?

Comment: That definitely isn't right, cause that just re-writes the container with 1.10 again.  I'll will look at the "build" link you posted and make sure I understand.